# C++ fast normal random number generator

Tags: c++, random, normal-distribution

I'm using the `mt19937` generator to generate normal random numbers as shown below:

```
normal_distribution<double> normalDistr(0, 1);    
mt19937 generator(123);
vector<double> randNums(1000000);
for (size_t i = 0; i != 1000000; ++i)
{
    randNums[i] = normalDistr(generator);
}
```

The above code works, however since I'm generating more than 100 million normal random numbers in my code, the above is very slow.

Is there a faster way to generate normal random numbers?

The following is some background on how the code would be used:

- Quality of the random numbers is not that important
- Precision of the numbers is not that important, either `double` or `float` is OK
- The normal distribution always has mean = 0 and sigma = 1

---

**EDIT**:

@Dúthomhas, Andrew:

After profiling the following function is taking up more than 50% of the time:

```
std::normal_distribution<double>::_Eval<std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int,32,624,397,31,2567483615,11,4294967295,7,2636928640,15,4022730752,18,1812433‌​253> >
```

Comment: I'm not convinced it's the RNG. Have you profiled your code?

Comment: @user2079303 I was incorrect.  It should have said: instead of using `vector<double> randNums(1000000);` you can use `vector<double> randNums; randNums.reserve(1000000);`.  That will save the time of setting all of the elements to 0.

Comment: Perhaps you could look into not generating 100 million random numbers. Why do you need so much?

Comment: Why do you need to store them in a giant array, instead of generating them on the fly?  Depending on the code consuming them, it might be best to generate them as needed.  This would only be a problem if your hot loop is bumping up against the limits of I-cache / uop-cache size.  (see http://agner.org/optimize/).  Or maybe if you need them inside a loop that benefits from keeping a lot of state in registers, so a non-inlined function call would mean spilling a lot of registers to memory.  Still, mt19937 has `uint32_t state[624]`.  I think it's fast for the quality, though.

Comment: You're asking a question about optimisation. Please include the results of _profiling_ your code. There's a good chance that the bottleneck isn't where you think it is.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: After profiling I can confirm that the following function is taking up 50% of the time: std::normal_distribution<double>::_Eval<std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int,32,624,397,31,2567483615,11,4294967295,7,2636928640,15,4022730752,18,1812433253> >

Comment: @user2079303: I'm doing a monte carlo simulation that involves 1 million paths and 500 time steps. That's why I need more than 100 million random numbers.

Comment: @chengcj I predict that rest of your monte carlo simulation is going to be more expensive computationally than the generation of the random numbers so that optimizing the random number generation may turn out to be almost pointless.

Comment: @everyone that thinks high-quality RNGs and mapping them to a normal distribution is cheap: By my (sleepy-headed) count while single-stepping in gdb, it takes **about 485 instructions per iteration** of the number-generating loop, [when compiled with gcc 5.2 `-O3 -ffast-math`](http://goo.gl/ow4Q2W).  (I think I lost count once or twice).  Many of those are FP mul and add, which have 3 and 5-cycle latency (on Intel SnB).  So it's **not cheap** to generate a random number and map it to a normal distribution.  (BTW, I think a *lot* of the cost is from the normal distribution, not the MT PRNG).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most importantly, do you really need 100,000,000 random numbers *simultaneously*? The writing to and subsequent reading from RAM of all these data unavoidably requires significant time. If you only need the random numbers one at a time, you should avoid that.

Assuming that you do need all of these numbers in RAM, then you should first
profile your code if you really want to know where the CPU time is spent/lost.

Second, you should avoid unnecessary re-allocation and initialisation of the data. This is most easily done by using `std::vector::reserve(final_size)` in conjunction with `std::vector::push_back()`.

Third, you could use a faster RNG than `std::mt19937`. That RNG is recommended when the quality of the numbers is of importance. The [online documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) says that the [lagged Fibonacci generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagged_Fibonacci_generator) (implemented in [`std:: subtract_with_carry_engine`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/subtract_with_carry_engine)) is fast, but it may not have a long enough recurrence period -- you must check this. Alternatively, you may want to use `std::min_stdrand` (which uses the [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator))

```
std::vector<double> make_normal_random(std::size_t number,
                                       std::uint_fast32_t seed)
{
  std::normal_distribution<double> normalDistr(0,1);    
  std::min_stdrand generator(seed);
  std::vector<double> randNums;
  randNums.reserve(number);
  while(number--)
    randNums.push_back(normalDistr(generator));
  return randNums;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You also will want to look into std::vector reserve rather than resize. It will allow you get all the memory you will need in 1 shot. I am assuming you don't need all 100 million doubles at once?

Answer (score 0):

If it really is the generator that is the cause of the performance degradation then use the ordinary `rand` function (you need to draw numbers in pairs), transform to a float or double in 0, 1 then apply the Box Muller transformation.

That will be hard to beat in terms of time, but note that the statistical properties are no better than `rand`.

A numerical recipes routine gasdev does this - you should be able to download a copy.

Comment: `std::normal_distribution` does that already (Box-Muller transform). Usage of `rand()` in C++ cannot be recommended.

Comment: Numerical recipes is not free software, but requires a licence.